# Changing source control type in TFS 2013

Tags: git, tfs, tfvc

I'm just setting up a TFS project using Team Foundation Server 2013. It will be reasonable simple - it will have

- Work Items and Project Tracking
- Source Control
- Automated Builds defined and working

There is a reasonable chance that we will change source control from Git (which we use currently) to Team Foundation Version Control. What I would like to do is set up the project in as fully as I can then swap version control if we need to. I think that this is impossible to do within the project (i might be wrong) so what is the best way to export all work items and build definitions and keep the state of both. I know it's possible to export a flat file of work items for instance but would I lose any linkages to features (for instance). I don't mind a bit of manual setup but I want to minimise this.

To summarise - how can I take a TFS project and swap the version control in the easiest way.

Cheeky extra question - if anyone has any horror stories about TFVC 2013 I would be really interested to know (a comment maybe). I know people struggled with TFS2012 but do local workspaces make it easier

Comment: Here's the opinion-based part of my answer: I think that Git is overcomplicated and almost intentionally obtuse. TFVC is excellent and has a much lower learning curve. There are definitely use cases for Git, but I think there's a ton of Git cargo-culting going on in the industry where people aren't evaluating the tools on their own advantages and disadvantages relative to what their team needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the source control type of an existing team project. However, you can migrate history and source code from one to another fairly easily. There are plenty of tools out there to help you accomplish that -- your search engine of choice can help you find them.

Your best bet, though, is to choose a source control tool up front and stick with it -- Git and TFVC have very different branching models, so you'd almost definitely encounter some pain in migrating the source code.